# How do I get the onclick "action" of a link using Python and Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping a job board (eluta.ca) using Python and Selenium.

I'm able to return everything I want except for the link to the extended job description.  In the bit of HTML below the job "Claims Adjuster"; links to "http://www.eluta.ca./direct/p?i=f1a7daa360e9468d5837d821c9d328ec"

```
<h2 class="title">

    <span class="lk-job-title" title="Claims Adjuster" onclick="enav2('./direct/p?i=f1a7daa360e9468d5837d821c9d328ec')"></span>

</h2>
```

I can find the element using the code

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#organic-jobs .organic-job:nth-child("+str(Line)+") .title .lk-job-title")
```

retrieve the job via .text, navigate to the extended description via .click()

Am I missing sometingh obvious that would return all or part of `"enav2('./direct/p?i=f1a7daa360e9468d5837d821c9d328ec')"`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute):

```
element = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#organic-jobs .organic-job:nth-child("+str(Line)+") .title .lk-job-title")
print element.get_attribute('onclick')
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  Where do I find this type of information so I can help myself in the future?

Comment: @PatrickR400 well, [selenium-python docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) are pretty detailed. I usually check it out first in case of any questions. Thank you.